# Unable to install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am having some issues with wsgi and getting my django api up and running using apache. I think the issue is the mod_wsgi.so. I have already installed `libapache2-mod-wsgi`, but my venv is configured using python 3.6. Based on my research I think I need `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`.

Trying to install with `sudo yum install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` returns

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | 3.7 kB  00:00:00
No package libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Error log shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660246 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]    File ".../project/project/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660275 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]      from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660283 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]    File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660295 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]      from django.utils.version import get_version
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660302 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]    File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660313 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]      from django.utils.regex_helper import _lazy_re_compile
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660319 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]    File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/regex_helper.py", line 10, in <module>
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660330 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]      from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660336 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]   File ".../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 362, in <module>
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660357 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]      class SimpleLazyObject(LazyObject):
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660375 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]  TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
[Tue Dec 20 19:02:24.660378 2022] [:error] [pid 13266]      'property' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the package error. For anyone wondering I ran `yum search wsgi` and discovered that the `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` is actually `python3-mod_wsgi.x86_64`.